# Is there a way to find all webpages with specific CSS classes or id's? A search engine for markup?

Tags: html, css, search, disqus

I'm trying to find websites with the Disqus commenting platform implemented (see a post on avc.com for reference). All Disqus comments are contained within a div with the id "disqus_thread". I've tried searching for words that appear within Disqus' comments interface such as "Real-time updating is" and "Subscribe by email" but it appears Google doesn't index those words.

Is there a search engine for markup, or an easy way to quickly scrape many sites for specific markup? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently building a tool capable of that. It is based on [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), which you could use for your goal. But that would involve some development effort.

But currently i am not aware of a search engine capable of that.